# Xpath with xmlns

Tags: xml, xpath

Although there are tons of question on Xpath and xmlns, I am not able to achieve desired result.

My xml is :-

```
<project xmlns = "https://afdsl/skdflsk/d"><name>AMCR_Positions</name><property name="included" type="hidden">true</property><locales><locale>en</locale><locale>de</locale></locales>
    <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
<namespace><name locale="en">AMCR_Positions</name>
           <name locale="de">AMCR_Positions</name>
        <lastChanged>2015-04-06T17:37:40</lastChanged>
        <lastChangedBy>I575079</lastChangedBy>
        <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
            <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
                <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qskxyz</name>
                    <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">qixyz</name>
                        <hello>searchTerm</hello>
                    </queryItem>
                </querySubject>
            </namespace>
 </namespace>
 <namespace>
        <name locale="en">Names</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
            <namespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
                <querySubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
                    <queryItem>
                    <name locale="en">myName</name>
                        <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                    </queryItem>
                </querySubject>
            </namespace>
 </namespace>
 </project>
```

My xpath :- `//*[local-name()='namespace']/*[local-name()='querySubject']/*[local-name()='queryItem'][contains(., 'searchTerm')]/*ancestor-or-self::*/name`

Or simplified version :- `//namespace//querySubject/queryItem[contains(.,'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name`

This works with xml without namespace but when there is namespace it fails. I have searched all way I am using vbscript program so I don't want to bind namespace rather I prefer pure Xpath.

Comment: This really is not the right way to do it. You should bind a prefix (say p) to your namespace "https://afdsl/skdflsk/d" using whatever mechanism your XPath API provides, and then use `//p:namespace/p:querySubject']/p:queryItem'][contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/p:name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "My XPath" part currently shows invalid XPath expression i.e `/*ancestor-or-self::*`, and you forgot to use `local-name()` matching for `name` element at the end of the XPath. Below is the corrected version of your XPath (wrapped into lines to make it more readable) :

```
//*[local-name()='namespace']
 /*[local-name()='querySubject']
 /*[local-name()='queryItem'][contains(., 'searchTerm')]
 /ancestor-or-self::*
 /*[local-name()='name']
```

Quick demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5aa4726e3bcd606dd657ca69aa4ac4ec

Comment: Thanks a lot man, What should I do if I want to select few ancestors compared to all ancestors in current code.

Comment: Requirement statement in your comment is too vague: *select few ancestors compared to all ancestors*. If you could post a proper question about that i.e sample XML + elements to be selected + current XPath attempt, I'll see if there is a way.